# How to trigger onclick by pressing enter using inline javascript?

Tags: javascript

[FYI: i am not allowed to change how it was marked up. div will be clicked.. not a button or anchor]

i have a menu(that should pass on accessibility standards) that will open its submenu when clicked.

this is the onclick function, and i need to do the same function when pressing enter key,

```
 // parent menu (this will repeat)        
    <div onclick="javascript:ToggleMenu('Calendar');" class="menu-item" style="cursor: hand;" tabindex="2">
        <p>Calendar</p>
        </div>

//submenu (this will repeat)
            <div id="Calendar" class="menu-subitem" style="display: none;" tabindex="2">


            <a onclick="Audit(this)" tabindex="2" href="Calendar/CalendarAssignment.aspx" id="TM_C1">Calendar Assignment</a>
             <a onclick="Audit(this)" tabindex="2" href="Calendar/ShiftAssignment.aspx" id="TM_C2">Shift Assignment</a>
            </div>
```

thanks!
i tried my best to be clear whew!

Comment: no option for changing to `input type submit`?

Comment: Pressing enter anywhere on the page? Also drop the `javascript:`, it does nothing.

Comment: no option like that.. just onlick.. and i have to do it also on key press..

Comment: You really should be using a `button`. See https://danielnixon.org/adventures-in-stack-overflows-html-tag/#clickable-divs-spans-etc

Comment: FYI: i am not allowed to change how it was marked up. div will be clicked.. not a button or anchor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the *accessible* solution while keeping a `div`:

```
<div id="foo" role="button" tabindex="0">Toggle menu</div>

<script>
    $('#foo').click(function() {
        ToggleMenu('<%# Container.DataItem.FuncID %>');
    }).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 32 || e.which === 13) {
          this.click();
        }
    });
</script>
```

But honestly you should just use a `button`:

```
<button id="foo">Toggle menu</button>

<script>
    $('#foo').click(function() {
        ToggleMenu('<%# Container.DataItem.FuncID %>');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I hate to dust off an old chestnut, but the question was not tagged jquery.  Butthis clearly is a positive contribution to the discussion. plus one

Answer (score 0):

This will do it when they hit the enter key anywhere on the page

```
<div onclick="javascript:ToggleMenu('<%# Container.DataItem.FuncID %>');">
<script>
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function (evt)
    {
        if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
            //they pressed enter

            //now get the divevent
            var div = document.querySelector('div[onclick*="ToggleMenu"]');
            //trigger the event
            div.onclick.apply(div);
        }
    }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: This needs `role="button"`, `tabindex="0"` and you need to trigger the click for space bar as well.

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: See https://danielnixon.org/adventures-in-stack-overflows-html-tag/#clickable-divs-spans-etc

Comment: the question was about javascript so I don't see how HTML standards are in the discussion, nor did OP ask about the space bar

Comment: which isn't to say those things aren't important, I just don't think they are required for this answer, especially since the question was not tagged HTML. If mine was the only answer then I could understand an edit, but it doesn't seem necessary since you have those things covered in your answer

Comment: hi @chiliNUT, tnx for answering.. how can i make it work for all menu? its just working in the first menu.

Comment: I can't say, you haven't posted any code relating to the menu :-)

Comment: @chilinut please see the edited version.. i tried too hard making myself clear.. im sorry haha

Comment: @xawi I dont know what you want to do. it wouldnt make sense for hitting enter to trigger every menu.

Comment: @chiliNUT, i am making all functionality available from a keyboard.. even opening the submenu of a menu..

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have an error in your code

`onclick"javascript:xxxx"`

is not correct,

```
"javascript:xxx"
```

should using on "a" tag "href" attribute, just remove the "javascript:" in your onclick attribute and you may get what you want.

Comment: should be a comment not an answer